# How do I get the download time of a file with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a webpage where I need to know how many time takes the download of a file. I'm trying to use ajax but since it's asynchronous i don't know how to track the moment when the download finishes on client.

Comment: Issue a http request from the ajax callback client-side indicating successful download completion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your browser's dev tools. All browsers have a network tab which can be used to inspect how long every request takes.